# for loop incrementation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm a beginner in iOS development so here is my question,

i m trying to implement a simple battle ship game and i manually placed my ships into allCoordinates array, the first element is x coordinate , second element is y coordinate and third one is the size of the ship.

The problem is; hit and missed must be increased just once for each try but when user enter 6th ship the hit became 1 and miss became 5 since the loop continue to check each row and increase miss.

I can't just put a break after the missed++ so i m out of ideas here.

Thank you :

```
for ( int i=0 ;i<19;i++ ){


    if ([self.xCoordinate.text isEqualToString:[allCoordinates objectAtIndex:i*3]] && 
        [self.yCoordinate.text isEqualToString:[allCoordinates objectAtIndex:i*3+1]] )

    {



        NSLog(@"hit");

        hit++;

        result.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You hit %ix1 ship",[allCoordinates objectAtIndex:i*3+2]];

        break;
    }else {

        NSLog(@"not hit");
       result.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You missed"];


        missed++;

    }

hitLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i!",hit];

missed = missed%18;

missedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i!",missed];
```

and this is my array

```
allCoordinates = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                          @"15",@"2",@"3",
                          @"13",@"2",@"3",
                          @"14",@"2",@"3",
                  @"10",@"7",@"3",
                  @"11",@"7",@"3",
                  @"12",@"7",@"3",
                    @"16",@"8",@"3",
                    @"16",@"9",@"3",
                    @"16",@"10",@"3",
                          @"3",@"4",@"4",
                          @"4",@"4",@"4",
                          @"5",@"4",@"4",
                          @"6",@"4",@"4",
                  @"9",@"10",@"4",
                  @"9",@"11",@"4",
                  @"9",@"12",@"4",
                  @"9",@"13",@"4",
                          @"5",@"14",@"1",
                          @"18",@"17",@"1",
                            nil];
```

edit:i fixed it by putting an BOOL ishit after the for loop and it fixed my problem

```
   if(ishit==YES){

    hit++;

}else {
    missed++;
}
```

Comment: why cant you put a break after missed?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but why are you using strings containing numbers rather than just numbers?

Comment: @GradyPlayer when i put break after missed the loop stop after the first try but it has to check all of them.

Comment: ugh oh yeah... so why doesn't it just run through the loop then? I don't like that hard coded 19 in the for loop, that makes me nervous.

Comment: There's very little value added by using NSObjects here; You're better off (memory & performance wise) using a C array of rows & columns and storing the ship sizes in the appropriate elements of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in hits, count the hits during the loop. Don't count the misses. It would seem that the count doesn't matter anyway, so just use a `BOOL` for if anything has been hit. After the loop, if there are any hits then set the hit text. If not, all are misses and you should set the miss text.

Comment: the count does matter.The score going to be calculated according the the count of missed and hit

Comment: well i inspired from your answer and found the answer thank you